# ignore exponent of a word in dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe where there are columns which have exponent in their values(strings/words).

Example

[image: word with exponent]
[image]

Pandas reads them as Rasha, Fatiguec,Pyrexiab. is there any way i can make it read properly. or even some other way to remove the exponent in those words

**UPDATE:** I found the solution under this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309887/pandas-read-html-ignore-superscripts-and-subscripts

Comment: A somewhat similiar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503565/replace-unicode-numeral-subscript-or-superscript-with-plain-numeral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to manually exclude those superscript letters aferwards - possibly even directly via the underlying code. Take a look at the wikipedia page regarding [Unicode Subscripts and Superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Quick and dirty example code via the particular superscript character:

```
import re

text = "Rashᵃ"
re.sub("(ᵃ)", '', text)

Out[1]: 'Rash'
```

Comment: thanks bt i need to read a file. i found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309887/pandas-read-html-ignore-superscripts-and-subscripts